# Way to make the directory universal (relative?) across different computers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

I am a high school student building a video game for a project, and you'll have to excuse me, I am very new to python/coding in general.
I assumed this would be a relatively easy thing to figure out or find online but I haven't had any luck. Obviously with a video game there are assets and files that need to be used. How can I set the directory to something that will work if run on another computer. More details below:

Right now I have it set to os.chdir(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\VideoGame'), and obviously if run on another computer the path would be different. How can I set it so it find that "VideoGame" file and then sets that as the directory.

Obviously I need a directory so python can find all the files I need. But let's say i take my folder with my code and all my assets on it and put it on a USB stick, then give it to my teacher, how can I be sure that the python he is running can find and use the files in that folder.

Comment: How do you package the game for distribution? Will something here be of help to you: https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: @RomanSusi I appreciate it but it doesn't look like it will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you clarified, what I understood is that you want to load all your game assets in a removable drive. I am assuming you will be having the `assets` folder in the directory where the `main.py` file will be present.

So my approach to the problem is to first obtain the current working directory of the `main.py` file and then add `assets\` to it and then check if that directory actually exists or not. If yes, then carry on with the operation, else display an error message.

My solution:

```py
import os 
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
dir_path = os.path.join(dir_path, r"assets")
if(os.path.exists(dir_path)):
    # block of code
    print()
else:
    print("assets not found!\ncheck your directory")
```

If I am again missing out something, fell free to comment.

Comment: Let me see if I can make it a bit more clear. Obviously I need a directory so python can find all the files I need. But let's say i take my folder with my code and all my assets on it and put it on a USB stick, then give it to my teacher, how can I be sure that the python he is running can find and use the files in that folder. I hope that makes more sense

Comment: @S.Lowe I have edited my answer. Check if this solves your problem.